# get end date automatically using specific days in php

Tags: php, using, days

When Start date is given it should get the end date by fetching only sunday or mon, tue, wed or ,mon to fri or  tue, thurs, sat using php. pls anyone help me.....

---

```
Here is my html code:




 <label>Start Date:</label><input type="text" id="txtStartDate" name="sd"></input>
 <td>days</td>
<td>
<select name="days">
    <option value="" >only sunday</option> 
    <option value="batch">sat and sun</option>
    <option value="">M-F</option>
    <option value="">M-W-F</option>
    <option value="">TU-THUR-SAT</option>
 </td>
 <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="sub"  />
 </td>

<?php
//$startdate=$_POST['sd'];
$startdate='2013-12-25';
$date=date_create($startdate);
date_add($date,date_interval_create_from_date_string("10 days"));
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
?>
```

---

it only fetches using number of days but i want to get using specific days.

Comment: I suggest explaining your question better with some examples. It's a little hard to understand

Comment: Using the given options and start date i want to get the end date. The above code only fetches using no of days. (i.e) i need to get the enddate using startdate and it should fetch only sunday or etc..from the start date and should display the end date

Comment: I understand that you know what you mean, but it's not quite coming across clearly. Sorry about that. Do you mean getting something like next wednesday?? If you could provide a bit more of a backstory eg. why you're doing this, it might shed some light on it for us, so we can help you out :)

Comment: ...I think I know what you mean....do you mean only get the days between the startdate and (startdate + 10) that are eg. Wednesday, Thursday or Friday??

Comment: Or like give an example. 
Like if I say start date is today, and I pick only sunday, what should the result be?

Comment: i wanna get end date.for eg:" if option 'only sunday' is selected it should show the end date only fetching 10 sundays and display the end date ".I hope so nw u understand my que

Comment: excatly @paquino and Ross Wilson

Comment: So, get the dates  for the next 10 sundays (10 weeks); or if Mon, Tues, Wed, the date for (Mon, Tues, Wed (next week) (Mon, Tues, Wed (the week after) (Mon, Tues, Wed (3rd week) and then Monday (4th) which will give 10 dates?

Comment: @Ross Wilson: ya excatly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store that days that you want to use in the option values ie

```
<select name="days">
    <option value="sunday" >only sunday</option> 
    <option value="saturday-sunday">sat and sun</option>
    <option value="monday-tuesday-wednesday-thursday-friday">Monday to Friday</option>
    <option value="monday-wednesday">Only Monday or Wednesday</option>
</select>
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST['sd']) && isset($_POST['days'])) {

    $startDate = new DateTime($_POST['sd']);
    $days = explode('-', $_POST['days']);
    $count = count($days);
    $dates = array();

    $currentDate = $startDate->format('Y-m-d');
    $j = 0;

    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {

        $day = $days[$j];
        $a = new DateTime($currentDate);
        $a->modify("next $day");
        $dates[] = $currentDate = $a->format('Y-m-d');

        $j = (($j+1) == $count) ? 0 : $j++; 

    } 

    foreach ($dates as $date) {
        echo $date.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**

or if you only want the last one of the array:

instead of the `foreach` use

```
echo end($dates);
```

Comment: :)this one works nice but i wanna to fetch ly the last date 4m this..

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "ly the last date 4m this"?

Comment: @user3132845 I've made an edit to my answer. I'm not sure if this is what you meant though.

Comment: hey it works. thank u so much.... but  its not fetching saturday and sunday,its only fetches saturday and other option also like that
  ** Will u please tell me how to get it.  **

Comment: I though you only wanted it to get the last date. If you give me a detailed example of what you expect to get out of it i.e. 1) What the user will select. 2) The start date that will get used. 3) What you expect to get out of it (what date(s) you should see). :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using strtotime

```
    <option value="SUNDAY" >only sunday</option> 
    <option value="SATSUN">sat and sun</option>
    <option value="MF">M-F</option>
    <option value="MWF">M-W-F</option>
    <option value="TUTHURSAT">TU-THUR-SAT</option>


    <?php

    $option = //get selected option;
    $startDate = //get selected date;
    $days = array();
    switch($option){
        case 'SUNDAY' : $days[] = 'next sunday'; break;
        case 'SATSUN' : $days[] = 'next saturday'; $days[] = 'next sunday'; break;
        //etc
    }

    $count = 0;
    $endDate = $startDate;
    while ($count < 10){
        $index = $count++ % count($days);
        $endDate = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime($days[$index] , strtotime($endDate)));
    }

    echo $endDate;
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca54a8b70da456b8799cdfd15d63c4e50cbe5b24)

Comment: paquino: it shows error in while part. will u pls explain this.

Comment: What's the error. Look at the Demo at the bottom.

Comment: Errors are
      Warning: Division by zero
      Notice: Undefined offset

Comment: Can you confirm that there are items in the $days array;
You need to match the switch cases with the option values in the HTML

Comment: no there s nothing inside it. i just copied ur code pasted it...

Comment: Well, did you copy and paste my solution exactly?
That's probably why it didn't work for you

You need to make the switch statement work with your select dropdown in the HTML

Comment: If you look at the $option and $startDate vars theyre empty, you need to set those with your own code. Past that, it should just work as long as the values of the select dropdown are like the ones I posted above

Comment: how to get the selected option in php